# JavaScript replace method replacing too much

Tags: javascript, replace

I am trying to use the `replace` method in JavaScript to strip out `<br>` and it is replacing way too much.

I am starting with a list of links in a database separated with `<br>`.  This is returned to the client via AJAX.  Links might look like:

```
 www.yahoo.com?d=asdadsf&s=aadsfasdf<br>www.gmail.com<br>www.twitter.com
```

I then run the `replace` method but it strips out everything after the `=` sign.

Here is the code:

```
function storeLinks() {

var links =  "www.yahoo.com?d=asdadsf&s=aadsfasdf<br>www.gmail.com<br>www.twitter.com";
alert(links);
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
//alert(text);
var newtext = text.replace(/<br>/g,""); //HERE PROBABLY LIES PROBLEM
//alert(newtext);
document.getElementById("links").textContent=newtext;//OR POSSIBLY HERE
    }
  }
//xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.open("GET","storelinks.php?links="+links,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Sorry, I cannot show this in a JSFiddle as it uses database on backend in AJAX call but I hope someone can spot the error in the `replace` syntax that is causing it to strip out way more than just the `<br>` tags.

Comment: If you want to replace single `<br>` use `text.replace("<br>","")`. However what exactly you need to replace at-least give example

Comment: You can use jsfiddle, Use a static representation of the data you would normally receive (fake data) and use their echo service. Or use jsbin's ajax support.

Comment: `"storelinks.php?"+links+"="+text` === `"storelinks.php?www.yahoo.com?d=asdadsf&s=aadsfasdf<br>www.gmail.com<br>www.twitter.com=undefined"` Your scopes are all off.

Comment: Also the question is not related to the problem. It's asking about regular expressions but the problem shown is a runtime error not a regular expression problem.

Comment: Your `replace` code works fine.  Is this line correct:  `"storelinks.php?"+links+"="+text,true)`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var x = "www.yahoo.com?d=asdadsf&s=aadsfasdf<br>www.gmail.com<br>www.twitter.com";
var y = x.split("<br>").join("").split("<br/>").join("");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sJC43/

Comment: Come on, a regexp will do this just fine: `text.replace(/<br\/?>/g, "")`

Comment: @Sukima Post it as an answer then, and yes regex certainly will be faster. I am showing different way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression works just fine. Your use of it is correct. The problem lies in some scoping issues and further diagnostics are blocked because you did not provide the data you receive from the server to see what the code is working with.

```
function storeLinks() {

  var xmlhttp;
  var links = "www.yahoo.com?d=asdadsf&s=aadsfasdf<br>www.gmail.com<br>www.twitter.com";

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // PLEASE STOP USING IE6, IE5!!!!
    // http://mashable.com/2011/03/04/ie6-countdown/
    throw new Error("IE6 is not supported!");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var ul;
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      ul = document.createElement('ul');
      this.responseText.split(/<br\s*\/?>/g)
        .map(function(link) {
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          li.textContent = link;
          return li;
        })
        .forEach(function(liTag) {
          ul.appendChild(liTag);
        });
    }
  };

  // "storelinks.php?www.yahoo.com?d=asdadsf&s=aadsfasdf<br>www.gmail.com<br>www.twitter.com=undefined"
  // ^ This does not make sense!
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "storelinks.php?" + links + "=" + text, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  return xmlhttp;
}
```

Comment: I tried your regex above and discovered, that the field is getting trunacted at the & point.  Everything else gets dropped.  So I am thinking I have to urlencode the links...  There was a typo in url of ajax call that I have fixed above